# Best Way to store application generated events

Tags: database, events, microservices

I'm building a microservices application using Node.js & PostgreSQL. Every module of this application is composed by 1 or more microservices that fullfill a specification.

For example, a module of this application is composed by two microservices:

- The first one downloads periodically a bunch of file, runs some validations against them and check the files contents.
- The second one, retrieve the files contents, organize the data and store the data in the db.

Every process has a list of events that can occur, for example

- File XX has not been downloaded | File XX has been downloaded
- File XX is valid for rule YZ | File XX is not valid for rule YY
- File XX has been successfully imported | File XX has an error during import
- etc...
  So every file can generate a lot of events, depending on download status, validation status, data status, import etc...

I need to keep track of this events because the end user must see them and "reconstruct" the whole file story in the system.

---

I need an hint on how to save and handle this events.
This kind of "generated events" can also come from other modules

I already tried this approach: use a couple tables in the first microservice DB to handle this data events, but my main concerns are

- data proliferation and data domain (i.e. based on the example above, some events belongs to the second microservice).
- Postgres (Relational DB in general) is the best way to handle this kind of data events?

I was also thinking to create an additional microservice that collects this events generated in the whole application and store them using some kind of database or use a completely external service (log collector?)

How would you approach this challenge? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a timeseries database like InfluxDB or TimescaleDB (a postgres extension for timeseries) to store such events with a very high write performance but with worse read performance than RDBMS (since timeseries dbs tend to use LSM-trees while RDBMS use B-trees).

Also, timeseries dbs often store their data in such a way that data points of the same type are next to each other, which allows for optimal compression algorithms to be used unlike RDBMS which store data in rows on disk, with the different data types next to each other which limits what type of compression algorithms can be used and how much data can be compressed.

Also, timeseries dbs tend to be schemaless which is another advantage.

You might want to look at distributed tracing tools like Jaeger.

Still you can use a relational database for this you might face some challenges when you need to scale.

Answer (score -1):

The classic way is to send your messages into a Kafka topic (https://kafka.apache.org/). From there, the messages can be consumed by other microservices. Be sure to use the "at least one" semantic (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics) to do not loose any message (but be prepared to eventually read the same message twice).